# OpenShift Origin Nodes WIth Multiple Network Interfaces

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Is it possible to configure OpenShift to use a separate interface on nodes+masters? For example, let's say I have a cluster where each machine has two network interfaces on different subnets (separated by VLANs). I would like to segregate traffic into two groups:

1. Administrative traffic (SSH)
2. OpenShift traffic (routes, intra-node communications, etc.)

Note in this config that the Administrative interface (eth0) is the default interface.

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Openshift-Ansible install probably fails due to multiple interfaces. I am using Vagrant for multip-node setup and Vagrant uses eth0 for ssh, and everything must go over eth1.